# ws.Cells to validate an If or select cells

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I'm trying to open another file on the network and then copy columns matching my original Excel file.

The Cells function does not allow me to validate the If nor select cells.

```vb
Sub pull_columns()

Dim head_count As Integer
Dim row_count As Integer
Dim col_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")

head_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight)))

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\...\CC_Global_Log_File_Scenario_Split.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate

row_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)))
col_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlToRight)))

For i = 1 To head_count
    j = 1
    Do While j <= col_count
        If ws.Cells(2, i) = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, j).Text Then
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, j), Cells(row_count, j)).Copy
            ws.Cells(2, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            j = col_count
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
Next i

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

ws.Cells(2, 1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous, it's difficult to tell what issues you're having. However, I can see that some of your references are unqualified. I've re-written your code slightly, and made sure all Ranges etc. are now qualified (i.e. the worksheet is stated in the code, rather than implied):

```
Option Explicit
Sub pull_columns()

    Dim head_count As Integer
    Dim row_count As Integer
    Dim col_count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourcewkb As Workbook
    Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    
    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = wkb.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    head_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlToRight)))
    
    Set sourcewkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\CC_Global_Log_File_Scenario_Split.xlsx")
    Set sourcesheet = sourcewkb.Worksheets("Automotive")
    
    row_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(sourcesheet.Range("A3", sourcesheet.Range("A3").End(xlDown)))
    col_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(sourcesheet.Range("A3", sourcesheet.Range("A3").End(xlToRight)))
    
    For i = 1 To head_count
        j = 1
        Do While j <= col_count
            If ws.Cells(2, i).Value = sourcesheet.Cells(3, j).Value Then
                sourcesheet.Range(Cells(3, j), sourcesheet.Cells(row_count, j)).Copy
                ws.Cells(2, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                j = col_count
            End If
        j = j + 1
        Loop
    Next i
    
    sourcewkb.Close savechanges:=False
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Perhaps that will solve your problem? If nothing else, it makes it easier to read/follow - and might help you describe the issue further.

Comment: Hey CLR, thanks for the reply. Actually my code was ignoring the If sentence i guess because my ws.Cells statement wasn't really able to pull any value? Anyway i ran your modification but after declaring "source" as Worksheet i'm havin compile issues in this line: Set source = Workbooks.Open("C:\...\CC_Global_Log_File_Scenario_Split.xlsx").   I'm obviously using the complete path.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I can see what I've done. I've set the Workbook to a Worksheet object. When the CC_Global_Log_File_Scenario_Split.xlsx is opened, what is the name of the sheet you want to be reading?

Comment: The Sheet is called "Automotive"

Comment: I've altered my answer, give that a try..

Comment: It definitely worked!! Thank you!

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, don't forget to mark this answered.